# Issue with multiple sessions

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

In my application I'm using SQLAlchemy for storing most persistent data across app restarts. For this I have a `db` package containing my mapper classes (like `Tag`, `Group` etc.) and a support class creating a single engine instance using `create_engine` and a single, global, `Session` factory using `sessionmaker`.

Now my understanding of how to use SQLAlchemys sessions is, that I don't pass them around in my app but rather create instances using the global factory whenever I need database access.

This leads to situations were a record is queried in one session and then passed on to another part of the app, which uses a different session instance. This gives me exceptions like this one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "…", line 29, in delete
    session.delete(self.record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1444, in delete
    self._attach(state, include_before=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1748, in _attach
    state.session_id, self.hash_key))
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<Group at 0x7fb64c7b3f90>' is already attached to session '1' (this is '3')
```

Now my question is: did I get the usage of `Session` completly wrong (so I should use one session only at a time and pass that session around to other components together with records from the database) or could this result from actual code issue?

Some example code demonstrating my exact problem:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr

Base = declarative_base()

class Record(Base):
    __tablename__ = "record"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%s('%s')>" % (type(self).__name__, self.name)

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

s1 = Session()

record = Record("foobar")
s1.add(record)
s1.commit()

# This would be a completly different part of app

s2 = Session()

record = s2.query(Record).filter(Record.name == "foobar").first()

def delete_record(record):
    session = Session()
    session.delete(record)
    session.commit()

delete_record(record)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I switched over to using a single, global session instance. That's neither nice nor clean in my opinion, but including lots and lots of boiler plate code to expunge objects from one session just to add them back to their original session after handing it over to some other application part was no realistic option, either.

I suppose this will completely blow up if I start using multiple threads to access the database via the very same session…